# Appearance of Menubar titles in gui

Tags: menu-bar

I have tried to get new version of Emacs using guix package manager. Which done successfully. Now I also have Emacs 26.1 alongside Emacs 24.

But I am facing a problem that the gui menu-bar titles appear as condensed. Little or no space in between. Please see the image.

[image]

I want it to look like properly legible and clear. I googled for the same but could not found the solution. Please guide me for that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that several fonts are missing - the default font for the editor should be monospaced. Consider installing a font package, like `font-liberation`, for example.

GUIX will only use its own fonts by default, and won't employ your system fonts.

Comment: I agree with @Haskell_Curry. I also noticed a size difference in the fonts on top (where it declares what version of Emacs is being used) and the fonts below it (FILE, EDIT....). It's possible that the fonts are set larger, likely in the X system itself. I also noticed that your Emacs font is large too. I've included my emacs to show you the difference, mine's 27.1 running on Windows 10 (work machine - my linux box is my REAL OS) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTBl1.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTBl1.jpg) Notice that the font on top, describing my system , is the